# How do I move one <div> in front of another <div>, and back?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two divs. One is in the front, and I want the one from the back to move right, and then back on top of the first one. I used jQuery, but it changes z-index immediately, and then proceeds moving one div to the right and back to the left to it's original position. This is how I've tried to do it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .block { 
        position: absolute; 
        background-color: #abc;
        left: 0px;
        top:30px;
        width: 60px; 
        height: 60px;
        margin: 5px; 
        }

        .block1 { 
        position: absolute; 
        background-color: red;
        left: 0px;
        top:30px;
        width: 60px; 
        height: 60px;
        margin: 5px;
        z-index: 999;
        }
    </style>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="block" onmouseout="hide();"></div>
<div class="block1" onmouseover="show();"></div>

<script>
function show() {
    $(".block").animate({left: '+=100px'}, 2000);
    $(".block1").css('zIndex', '-10000');
    $(".block").animate({left: '-=100px'}, 2000);
};

function hide() {
    $(".block").animate({left: '+=100px'}, 2000);
    $(".block1").css('zIndex', '10000');
    $(".block").animate({left: '-=100px'}, 2000);
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `animate` method is asynchronous. You have to change the z-index after you have finished the first animation by providing a callback function to the `animate` method:

```
function show() {
    $(".block").animate({left: '+=100px'}, 2000, function() {
        $(".block1").css('zIndex', '-10000');
        $(".block").animate({left: '-=100px'}, 2000);
    });
};
```

From the documentation for [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

> **complete**
>   Type: Function()
>   A function to call once the animation is complete.

Comment: Wow, that was quick :) Thanx! :)

Comment: @Nenad: If this answers has helped you, you should accept it.

Answer (score 1):

```
function show() {
    $(".block").animate({left: '+=100px'}, 2000, function() {
        $(".block1").css('zIndex', '-10000');
        $(".block").animate({left: '-=100px'}, 2000);
    });    
};

function hide() {
    $(".block").animate({left: '+=100px'}, 2000, function() { 
        $(".block1").css('zIndex', '10000');
        $(".block").animate({left: '-=100px'}, 2000);
    });
};
```

You have to fire remaining operations after the first animation is complete via a callback function.

Raidri beat me to it !

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use setimeout().

first you animate it to the left. Then after the setTimeout you can change the z-index and move it to the right!

here are some examples of setTimeout:
http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/settimeout-example/